# Should we allow every person their own tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

This is a list of people with their own tags here:

- [hitler](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hitler) x11
- [john-f-kennedy](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/john-f-kennedy) x4
- [mao-zedong](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mao-zedong) x2
- [saladin](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/saladin) x2
- [richard-i](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/richard-i) x2
- [vladimir-lenin](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vladimir-lenin) x1
- [stalin](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stalin) x1
- [alexander-iii-greece](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alexander-iii-greece) x1
- [king-dahir](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-dahir) x1
- [ngo-dinh-diem](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ngo-dinh-diem) x1

Aside from the [hitler](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hitler) and maybe the [john-f-kennedy](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/john-f-kennedy) tags, they are all rarely used. Should every historical person be eligible for their own tag? In my opinion, people you'll never hear of except in a [Wikipedia stub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yelena_Solovey) shouldn't have their own tag. But then, where should we draw the line? Should Thomas Jefferson get a tag? Should Livy get a tag? Should Ephialtes of Trachis get a tag? Should German Gardiner get a tag?

Should there be requirements for a person to get their own tag?

Comment: Is there any sort of detriment here?  I use tags at times to find related informtion, but they are only useful when used.

Comment: We don't have a huge user base now, but as the site grows, there will be more and more users with the privilege of creating tags. If everyone has the right to their own tag, we'll have hundreds of relatively unused tags. We could very easily have a problem with too many tags as other sites now have. Imagine every stub article on Wikipedia about a person getting it's own tag here. I believe we should draw the line now (and possibly change and improve it later) and act as deemed fit as we go along rather than drawing the line later and having to clean up the accumulated mess.

Answer (score 3):

I am all for tags for individuals of interest from history. I think there are definitely enough historical figures to justify it, and I would love to be able to peruse the tags and see a name I don't recognize thereby causing me to look the person.

Answer (score 2):

Well, for any tag you don't find in the least bit useful, you could in theory fix the problem yourself (assuming you have enough rep) by editing the one question containing it to no longer contain that tag.

I could see a case for doing that for the last three you mentioned. The rest seem useful to me.

Comment: I'll use the standard answer for many things and just say this is a community site, so if you have the rep make the changes if everyone agrees it's good.  If not, there will be a good question on it like this one.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with NewAlexandria's proposal - replace most tags that have 1-2 Qs each with a generic historical-persona tag.

---

Why?

Having random per-person tags with 1-2 questions pertaining to that person serves no useful purpose aside from cluttering tag namespace.

A tag is meant so people can either

- filter in/out questions for the tag - which 1-Question-tag doesn't help with
- classify questions when the volume is too high. Again, a class of 1-2 questions is useless for taxonomy.

NOTE: I'm an OCD classification fanatic, and usually argue against deleting any given tag on SFF.SE. So I'm inherently biased to more tags.

Answer (score -2):

I propose a [persona](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/persona) tag.

Then we re-tag all of the existing.

Comment: How much this tag would be useful for anybody who searches info?